# Algorithm to decide product/quantity values in a purchase

Tags: probability, algorithms

Imagine that every shirt/color pair has different cost price.

For Example:

```
Red shirt is $2 
Yellow shirt is $4
Blue shirt is $6
```

I would like to buy total 300 shirts and keep the average cost as $4. In this case I have many options:

```
0 x red = 0 x $2 = $0
300 x yellow = 300 x $4 = $1200
0 x blue = 0 x $6 = $0
Total quantity = 300, Total Cost = $1200, Average Cost is $4
```

or

```
100 x red = 100 x $2 = $200
100 x yellow = 100 x $4 = $400
100 x blue = 100 x $6 = $600
Total quantity = 300, Total Cost = $1200, Average Cost is $4
```

and many other options...

How can I find the **quantity** numbers which are close to eachother? 100x + 100y + 100z is the best option for the example mentioned above.

**Another Example with real numbers:**

```
White: 2.13 USD
Yellow: 3.12 USD   
Blue: 2.85 USD
Pink: 4.50 USD
Black: 5.45 USD
Red: 6 USD

Expected Average Cost is 3.50 USD
Total Item: 500
```

How many products should I buy so that the numbers are close (or has minimum distance if the expected price is too low) to each other? Can you help me to write a formula?

another scenario: if the **Expected Average Cost** is **2.13 USD**, it should return **500 x White** and **0(zero) for the others** since the result can have only 1 option.

Inputs: **total quantity** and **expected average cost** and **color/price data** (n colors)
Output: **color** / **suggested quantity** pairs

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: you can turn *real* case into *integer* problem by multiplying by `100`: we can use *cents* instead of *dollars*